# Auto Update in access application

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a problem here in Microsoft access vba application. I have my project with BE And FE files, So I want to trigger for the client when open the front end Before the app to open must check for update and if find any update will be downloaded to the specified folder.
Any help please

Comment: Study my article and script, that handles this: [Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application with one click](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33417/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-with-one-click.html?preview=X8LitkMCd/Y%3D).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I already have code to do this, I will post it here as an example.

Requires a table with a single record to hold the current frontend version number and form is bound to the table with a textbox displaying the version field. A label on form has version number of the published frontend.

This worked great until received new computers and IT security settings prevent programmatic copy of files. I had to modify code to simply notify users to manually copy/replace file, open folder, and abort the DB file opening.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
        
'Check for updates to the program on start up - if values don't match then there is a later version
If Me.tbxVersion <> Me.lblVersion.Caption Then
    'because administrator opens the master development copy, only run this for non-administrator users
    If DLookup("Permissions", "Users", "UserNetworkID='" & Environ("UserName") & "'") <> "admin" Then
        'copy Access file
        CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CopyFile _
            gstrBasePath & "Program\Install\MaterialsDatabase.accdb", "c:\", True
        'allow enough time for file to completely copy before opening
        Dim Start As Double
        Start = Timer
        While Timer < Start + 3
            DoEvents
        Wend
        'load new version - SysCmd function gets the Access executable file path
        'Shell function requires literal quote marks in the target filename string argument, apostrophe delimiters fail, hence the quadrupled quote marks
        Shell SysCmd(acSysCmdAccessDir) & "MSAccess.exe " & """" & CurrentProject.FullName & """", vbNormalFocus
        'close current file
        DoCmd.Quit
    End If
Else
    'tbxVersion available only to administrator to update version number in Updates table
    Me.tbxVersion.Visible = False
    Call UserLogin
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: But this Code didn't work online means on a website where the update is uploaded there. i want to get update on a server when the app is connected to Internet

Comment: Why did you mark this answer as accepted? Edit your question with this detail. Code for downloading file from webpage can be found in https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29679/Show-pictures-directly-from-URLs-in-Access-forms-and-reports.html or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577170/adding-images-from-internet-into-vba-image-control or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69927421/access-2003-how-to-display-an-image-from-url#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20method%20used%20in%20my,the%20control%20source%20for%20a%20bound%20picture%20control. How do you connect Access to internet?